# Flip the iPhone screen with a button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

how do I implement a button that will flip the screen 180deg for my game (if the user wishes to play it with the iPhone upside-down), and have it affect all of my 5 different views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply a transform to the parent view (your UIWindow). The rotation can be made using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()`.

It might be better to actually allow the device orientation to cause the rotation though. In App settings set that the app supports autorotation and then in the UIViewController return tru to `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` when the rotation passed in is `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`

Answer (score 1):

Look at shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. And maybe `[myView setNeedsDisplay];` could help.

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation returns a Boolean value indicating whether the view controller supports the specified orientation it does not perform the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to use the build in automatic orientation rotation.  You may need to tell your app in the build settings that it supports the upsidedown orientation and as dasdom mentioned you need to implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in all of your view controllers.

There is no way to force the phone into an orientation on-demand.

If you are looking to just rotate a view you can apply a CGAffineTransform.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  3 of us here have made similar recommnedations.  We can't all be that far off track.